# J2V8 ReferenceError : process is not defined, when trying to execute script

Tags: javascript, v8, nashorn, j2v8

I'm using J2V8 to call a javascript function from my Java code. When I try to execute my script it gives me ReferenceError : process is not defined. The script uses reactDomServer to transform a hash map into an html object.

I'm initializing my V8 as follows:

```
V8 v8 = v8.createV8Runtime("global");
```

Also, is there a way to pass a hashmap as parameter when you want to call a JS function using V8?

```
v8.executeJsScript("myFunction", myHashMap)
```

This was working with nashorn but im not able to make it work with V8. It seems my parameters need to be V8 values or primitives. All the examples I find are very simple and pass only strings or integers as parameters.. If my parameters are a few objects, should I declare them as V8 values and then push them in a V8 array and pass that array as my function parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `V8ObjectUtils.toV8Object` to create a V8Object from a HashMap.